# Function does not return any value in C

Tags: c, argument-passing

I'm trying to make a calculation in C and trying to return the result value of a mathematical calculation but nothing prints out to screen when passing to main fuction. I have tried various methods but something is missing. Can you help me correct the code in a way that will help me in the future to write more efficient code when passing arguments to main? Thanks in advance!

```
#include <stdio.h>

#define     PI      3.14159
#define     REM     144.612925

static double Raden_CALC(double imp)
{

    double result;
    result = ((imp + imp) * PI) / REM;
    return result;
}

main()
{

    double number;
    printf("Enter a number: ");

    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%.4lf", &number);

    Raden_CALC(number);
    printf("\nResult: ", number);
}
```

Comment: You ignored the returned value.  The function doesn't (can't) alter the input parameter.

Comment: Be very wary of [Using `fflush(stdin)`](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2979209/using-fflushstdin).  It is, at best, not portable.  Also, to ensure output appears in a timely manner, make sure outputs end with a newline: `printf("Result: %f\n", number);`.

Comment: …so, for example, instead of relying on this horrible piece of undefined behavior and the only slightly less horrible `scanf()`, you could (should) use `fgets()` and `strtod()`.

Comment: Thank you everyone! I don't usually commit that mistake but as a human being I keep forgetting adding % in the printf. Thanks yet again!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
int main()
{
    double number;
    printf("Enter a number: ");

    fflush(stdin);
    scanf("%.4lf", &number);

    number = Raden_CALC(number); // <-- Assign the return value to number 
    printf("\nResult: %f\n", number); // <-- Add %f to print the number
}
```

Comment: It still won't print because it's missing the `%f` in the last `printf`.

Comment: Thank you guys! It helped a lot! I don't know how I forgot to add %lf or %f into the printf()

Comment: `fflush(stdin)` is undefined behavior, I heard there is a compiler specific implementation of it, but learning that is more harmful than useful.

Answer (score 2):

You're not using the value from the function... change:

```
Raden_CALC(number);
printf("\nResult: %lf", number);
```

to

```
number = Raden_CALC(number);
printf("\nResult: %lf", number);
```

or

```
printf("\nResult: %lf", Raden_CALC(number));
```

Comment: As an aside, the `l` in the format-specifier is gratuitious for `printf`, but would not be for `scanf`.

Comment: @Deduplicator Yeah, I couldn't remember if the `l` was needed to print double or not.

Answer (score 1):

If you return something from a function you need to use the value returned.

```
double result=Raden_CALC(number);
printf("Result: %lf\n", result);
```

That might be a crazy explanation, but I'll try. If you ask someone "Please give me an apple", and he gives you one, what will you do? Here you're just ignoring it.

Comment: Yeah well, sometimes I really forgot to put % in the printf(). Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you want to modify the value in the function pass it's address and use the pointer to alter the data like this

```
void Raden_CALC(double *number)
 {
    *number = 2 * (*number * PI) / REM;
 }
```

and then in `main()`<sup>1</sup>

```
int main()
 {
    double number;

    printf("Enter a number: ");
    if (scanf("%.4lf", &number) == 1)
     {
        Raden_CALC(&number);
        printf("\nResult: %f", number);
     }
    return 0;
 }
```

also, don't `fflush(stdin)` because it's undefined behavior, and `printf()` cannot work as you used it, you need to pass a format specifier just like you do in `scanf()` and then it will replace them with the arguments you pass, in this case `number`.

You should also, check that `scanf()` worked and the input was valid, otherwise you will use an uninitialized value which causes undefined behavior.

The following was extracted from the C11 standard draft 1570:

> **7.21.5.2 The fflush function**
>
> **Synopsis**
>
> ```
>    #include <stdio.h>
>    int fflush(FILE *stream);
> ```
>
> 2. If `stream` points to an **output stream** or an **update stream** in which the most recent
>      operation was not input, the `fflush` function causes any unwritten data for that stream
>      to be delivered to the host environment to be written to the file; **otherwise, the behavior is undefined.**

To achieve the effect you think `fflush(stdin)` has you can use this

```
#define flushinput() do {                                    \
        int chr;                                             \
        while (((chr = getchar()) != EOF) && (chr != '\n')); \
    } while (0)
```

and then after `scanf()`ing use the macro as if it was a function.

---

<sup>1</sup><sub>Note that `main()` returns `int`.</sub>

Comment: So using fflush with characters and strings is best right? Just like the following example: scanf("%[^\n]", name); fflush(stdin); printf("Name: %s", name);

Comment: NO `fflush(stdin)` is always wrong because `fflush()` is defined for output streams only.

Comment: Yes but sometimes an error occurs for example when asking for 4 people to enter their names if not fflush is used then the compiler automaticly skips other scanf() and printout only the first scanf. I do understand now when reading about it but any better solutions?

Comment: That is not true, have you tried it? the only problems with `scanf()` is how it's used in the wrong way most of the time, ignoring it's returned value, and forgetting that it leaves the trailing `'\n'` characters, which causes some wierd behavior but you can always remove it with `getchar()`, `fflush(stdin)` is simply wrong.

Comment: Yes but can you try following code and give the feedback. Because it acted exactly the way I assumed it would. Skipped all scanf and printed out the all printf and didn't even asked to enter remaning 3 scanf.
#include <stdio.h>


main()
{

    char name[50];
    char name1[50];
    char name2[50];
    char name3[50];
    
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", name);
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", name1);
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", name2);
    printf("Enter your name: ");
    scanf("%[^\n]", name3);
}

Comment: It doesn't work with  `fflush(stdin)` it works if you gather the `'\n'` that was left in the input buffer like this `int chr; while (((chr = getchar()) != EOF) && (chr != '\n'));`, inserting it after every `scanf()` does the job, and in this case it would work better with `fgets()`.

Comment: ah all right, just noted but frankly I still haven't experienced anything wrong with fflush alongside with scanf string input but if you say it's not recommended then I do believe in it! After all you're  an experienced programmers

Comment: @CalFox I don't say it's not recommended the standard says it's undefined behavior.